# Karma can't find my tests in my angular-cli app

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Angular 4 project generated with CLI and I'm trying to make test work. I have Karma.conf in the root of my project:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And here is my test.ts located in my src folder:

```
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

__karma__.loaded = function () {};

getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
__karma__.start();
```

My folder structure is:

```
    +---app
|   +---class
|   +---components
|   +---services
|   \---templates
+---assets
|   \---images
\---environments
```

So, inside my components, I have created a test called `feeds.component.spec.ts` that is associated to a component called `feeds.component.ts`.

The output of my windows console is the following:

```
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

The package "angular-cli" has been deprecated and renamed to "@angular/cli".

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli"
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

08 05 2017 08:33:12.674:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost
:9876/
08 05 2017 08:33:12.687:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://loca
lhost:9876/
08 05 2017 08:33:12.688:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited
 concurrency
08 05 2017 08:33:12.897:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
08 05 2017 08:33:17.033:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on
 socket /#tif1xw_35N5kuco6ACBA with id 3123123
```

And karma debug console just outputs `Skipped 0 tests` so no test is being launched.

The strange thing is that I can launch default tests that are located in my `template` folder: `app.component.spec.ts`:

```
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (3 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.159
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (3 FAILED) ERROR (0.536 sec
s / 0.159 secs)
```

I've also tried "forcing" the test in my `karma.conf.js` by commenting the test.ts pattern and hardcoding my component:

```
files: [
  //{ pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
  { pattern: 'app/components/feeds.component.spec.ts', included: true, watched:false }
],
```

But this outputs the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at src/app/components/feeds.component.spec.ts:1
```

Why aren't my `components` test not being launched?

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:

```
  npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
  npm clean
  npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

you should also do it globally.

Answer (score 0):

For npm 5, I resolved this issue by:

- deleting `package-lock.json`;
- running `npm cache clean --force`;
- deleting any unnecessary dependencies from `package.json` (I had @ngtools);
- updating the rest of the dependencies using [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) and running `npm i` again.

I did have some issues with typescript 2.4.x afterwards and reverted to 2.3.4, but that will likely be resolved in a few days; it's worth mentioning for now.